# How to set multiple values

Tags: mysql, database

about this code:

```
AND posts_clases.ID in (select post_id from wp_postmeta wpm where wpm.meta_key="num_clas" and wpm.meta_value ='1' or wpm.meta_value ='25' or wpm.meta_value ='28')
```

Is possible to use a function for multiple values? (1,25,28)
wpm.meta_value = (multiple values)

Many thanks

Comment: `and wpm.meta_value in (1, 25, 28)`

Answer (score 0):

try `wpm.meta_value IN (1,25,28)`

Comment: Please explain your answer a little more.

Answer (score 0):

Zo get the correct rows  you need a parenthesis around your ORs, like

```
AND posts_clases.ID in (select post_id from wp_postmeta wpm where wpm.meta_key="num_clas" and (wpm.meta_value ='1' or wpm.meta_value ='25' or wpm.meta_value ='28'))
```

Or you use a IN clause

```
AND posts_clases.ID in (select post_id from wp_postmeta wpm where wpm.meta_key="num_clas" and wpm.meta_value IN ('1','25','28'))
```